# Is there a free tool for rendering a webpage to a PNG with a transparent background?

Tags: html, css, screen-capture, alpha-transparency

Say I have a very simple html page, containing a single line of text. I'm looking for a tool that would take that line of text, and superimpose it on a transparent PNG background. That logic would be applied to ALL elements on the page: if no `background` is specified, and the background of parent elements doesn't leak through, then a background should render as transparent.

As in transparent-pixel-in-image tranparent.

Is there a tool for this?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Tricky one. How to write a program to solve it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various command line tools for this sort of thing, most of which depend on WebKit somehow, eg. [webkit2png](http://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png/), the hard part is going to be making the background transparent.  Every screenshot tool I've ever tried sets the background opaque, even if the CSS background colour is `transparent`.  The best approach might be to set the background to some unusual colour by default and then use a tool like ImageMagick to [set that particular colour transparent](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#transparent).

Comment: Yep, setting the background to some arbitrary color should do the trick. In principle, if I use two different colors, I should be able to calculate the transparency perfectly.

Comment: But what about aliasing?